# juju 2.4.1 bootstrap openstack fails : NeutronError unexpected status: 400

Tags: juju, openstack

So I'm trying to bootstrap a controller inside my openstack cloud and it appears to be failing when trying to create the security group.

I believe this is happening because from the bootstrap debug I noticed that in the auth details there's no information for TenantId:

03:07:53 DEBUG goose client.go:511 auth details: &{Token:e755f8efd8b546c4bdcd1816aeeb0a65 TenantId: UserId:c98f1d30569b4712bd7b2dc80d38d09f Domain:admin_domain RegionServiceURLs:map[RegionOne:map[identity:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.174:5000/v3 object-store:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.164:80/swift/v1 placement:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.176:8778 network:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.169:9696 compute:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.176:8774/v2.1 image:http://xxx.xxx.xxx.175:9292]]}

The actual error in the debug is

caused by: request (http://xxx.xxx.xxx.169:9696/v2.0/security-groups) returned unexpected status: 400; error info: {"NeutronError": {"message": "Running without keystone AuthN requires that tenant_id is specified", "type": "HTTPBadRequest", "detail": ""}}

The error kinda makes sense because neutron would have no idea on which project to create the security group.

Does anyone know why the TenantId would not be declared, even though I declared this when running the juju add-credential.

my exact bootstrap command is :

juju bootstrap mycloudname.example.com juju-openstack-controller --metadata-source ~/simplestreams/images --config network=fef7b36b-8c2c-4a2c-a860-0ed826231730 --config use-floating-ip=yes  --config external-network=46fb58fc-6935-4e64-a54e-8c351370f184   --debug

Updated to 2.4.3 problem still persists
https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1785747

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'domain-name: admin_domain' to 'domain-name: ""' in your ~/.local/share/juju/credentials.yaml file, where the openstack cloud credentials are specified.  This has worked in at least one case.

A bug was created which is specific to this error:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1806985